# nw:weighted-path-to, nw:turtles-on-weighted-path-to and multiple equally weighted paths

Tags: netlogo

I apologise upfront if this is a stupid question.

When one calls *nw:weighted-path-to* a list of links is returned describing the shortest path between origin and destination turtles.

Similarly, calling *nw:turtles-on-weighted-path-to* returns a list of the turtles on the shortest path between origin and destination.

It is my understanding that if there are 2 equally weighted paths between origin and destination both functions returns one of these paths at random. This happens independently and as such one set of links can be produced for the shortest path, but another set of turtles.  This can be replicated using the following code:

```
extensions [nw]

links-own [ weight ]

to go
   clear-all
   create-turtles 4

   ask turtle 0 [ create-link-with turtle 1 [ set weight 2 ] ]
   ask turtle 0 [ create-link-with turtle 2 [ set weight 2 ] ]

   ask turtle 1 [ create-link-with turtle 3 [ set weight 2] ]
   ask turtle 2 [ create-link-with turtle 3 [ set weight 2] ]


   ask turtle 0 
   [
        let pathLinks nw:weighted-path-to turtle 3 "weight"
        let pathNodes nw:turtles-on-weighted-path-to turtle 3 "weight" 
        let pathUtility nw:weighted-distance-to turtle 3 "weight" 

        show pathLinks
        show pathNodes
        show pathUtility
   ]

end
```

Which will happily produce:

```
(turtle 0): [(link 0 2) (link 2 3)]
(turtle 0): [(turtle 0) (turtle 1) (turtle 3)]
(turtle 0): 4
```

Obviously, this is not an error but it has unfortunately tripped me up.

My question is - what is the most sensible way to link these two procedures to produce lists of links and turtles that make up a single randomly selected shortest path?

I am assuming it would be best to return the links with *nw:weighted-path-to*, then ask the links to return *both-ends* and do some sort of unique operation to produce a set of turtles on that path, if that is the case I'm not sure how to preserve the order of turtles. Does this make sense? Is that how you would do it?

As ever, thanks for reading.

Edit: *this also applies to path-to and turtles-on-path-to in a topological network with multiple equal length paths.*

Comment: This was at some point considered for inclusion as an extension primitive: https://github.com/NetLogo/NW-Extension/issues/64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question! You can generate either list from the other, but I think turtle-path to link-path is easier:

```
;; Construct the turtle path, putting the current turtle on the front:
let turtle-path fput self nw:turtles-on-weight-path-to turtle 3 "weight"

;; Iterate through pairs of turtles, getting the link connecting them
let link-path (map [[link-with ?2] of ?1] but-last turtle-path but-first turtle-path)
```

Edit:

Nicolas is absolutely right about "link-path to turtle-path". However, his comment made me realize you could use the almighty `reduce` and the ever-useful `other-end` to do it!

```
reduce [ lput [[other-end] of ?2] of (last ?1) ?1 ] fput (list self) nw:weighted-path-to turtle 3 "weight"
```

Edit2: The "link-path to turtle-path" code is pretty opaque. Here's an attempt to clarify it:

```
to-report add-link-to-turtle-path [ turtle-path next-link ]
  let last-turtle last turtle-path
  report lput [[other-end] of next-link] of last-turtle
end

;; turtle-procedure - Assumes the current turtle is the starting point of the path
to-report link-path-to-turtle-path [ link-path ]
  let start-of-path (list self)
  report reduce add-link-to-turtle-path fput start-of-path link-path
end
```

Comment: Yeah, in fact, "link-path to turtle-path" is surprisingly difficult, at least with undirected links, because `end1` and `end2` are not necessarily in "path order". If you have one link long path, there is no way to know what the order should be unless you've been holding on to either the starting or ending turtle.

Comment: Great answer! many thanks. And, more importantly perhaps, I have learnt about `reduce` - which seems like something I should have known about years ago. Thanks again.